# Shift plot in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to represent the plot for an isothermal ideal gas transformation. I tried the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $V$,
    ylabel = {$p$},
]
\addplot +[
    domain=0.2:5, 
    samples=50,
]
{1/x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the plot it is too *raw* (it has the points on axis and it is *tied* to the axis). This is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

I want to add those custom points on the axis and *shift* the plot. Could you provide some guidance, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plot is "tied to the axis" because the axis limits are adjusted automatically when you change the `domain`. So just state `xmin` and `ymin` values and you almost have, what you want.

In my following solution I just did some fine-tuning for the `domain` and hope that you will be able to add the labels yourself. (If not, let me know ...)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        ymin=0,
        axis lines=left,
        xlabel=$V$,
        ylabel={$p$},
        no markers,
        domain=0.5:3,
    ]
        \addplot {1/x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried using the `xmin`, `xmax` etc and `domain` but I was adding domain to the plot, not to the axis.

Comment: Should I add the labels using `tick` options?

Comment: @Victor That's one way, e.g. `xtick={1,2}, xticklabels={$v_1$,$v_2$}, ytick={0.5,1}, yticklabels={$P_2$,$P_1$}` in the `axis` options, and one of many ways to add the lines is `\addplot [densely dotted,black,ycomb,samples at={1,2}] {1/x}; \addplot [densely dotted,black,xcomb,samples at={1,2}] {1/x};`

Comment: @Victor, if you use `domain` in the `axis` or `\addplot` options doesn't matter. Regarding the labels -- as x already mentioned -- there are plenty of ways to do it. Have a look e.g. at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371524 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372487.